# Jquery Horizontal scrolling error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble implementing an jquery plugin that scroll horizontal. The problem is , it doesn't scroll horizontal even though , I followed each instruction .

Here is the demo:
http://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/demos/horizontal-scrolling/

My demo  http://jsbin.com/ezizoz/1

Can someone help me

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

  <html>
  <head>


  <script src="http://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/demos/horizontal-scrolling/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <script type = "text/javascript" src ="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('html, body, *').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
                this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
                e.preventDefault();
            });

        });
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>

  dwdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
  dwdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddwdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddwdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddwdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddwdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddwdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddwdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddwdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddwdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working.
Just swap the script lines. First include jquery file and then mousewheel file.

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/demos/horizontal-scrolling/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

also u have to include CSS..

then it works

http://jsbin.com/ezizoz/4

check this demo